# Facing error while trying to save the parameters on Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am encountering an error while attempting to save parameters in Power BI. I have connected Power BI and retrieved data from a local MongoDB using an ODBC driver.
[Click for See ODBC drivers connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgT84.png)
Then I added the date parameters.
[Parameters Defined in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr27M.png)
And then, when I tried to save this, I encountered this error.
[Error Message Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA7Zn.png)

**OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.12]This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.**

This is the query generated which I am trying to save.
[Power Query Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikuhC.png)

**= Table.SelectRows(demo_Table, each [hire_date] >= RangeStart and [hire_date] <= RangeEnd)**

I have tried changing connectors and refreshing connections, but I didn't find any resources that would help me resolve the problem.